# -webkit-filter: blur() doesn't work vue js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, filter, webkit

I'm trying to add -webkit-filter: blur (), but it doesn't work at all. I just tried "filter" but it doesn't work anyway.
I think it works in html, not in Vue or are there any alternatives?

```
<template>
  <div class="comingsoon">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <span class="msg">COMING SOON</span>
    <span class="notifymsg">GET NOTIFIED WHEN IT'S READY</span>
    <span class="field"></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

**The CSS**

```
.circle {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(#313247 0%, #19181D 30%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 35%;
}

.circle:before,
.circle:after {
    content: '';
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFD1DA 0%, #FF849D 5%, 2D2133 25%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
    z-index: -1;
}

.circle:after {
    width: 415px;
    top:35%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(14px);
    opacity: .3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple add this line it works!

```
span.circle {
    -webkit-filter: blur(14px);
}
```